# Как настроить соединение Ubuntu (FreeTDS) к именованному экземпляру MS SQL

Tags: unix-odbc

Как настроить соединение ubuntu (FreeTDS) к именованному экземпляру MS SQL?

Непонятно как именно указать в файлах `odbc.ini` и `freetds.ini` `host = (имя или ip)\имя экземпляра`

Все проверки ругаются на непонятность имени хоста. Остальные источники, подключенные к "новым" установкам (не имеющим в своем имени "\") работают отлично.

Comment: А как вы пытались указать?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо разобрался. Я вначале пробовал указать ServerName и InstanceName, не указывая номер порта, но подключиться не смог, видимо служба "Веб Браузер SQL" не смогла правильно интерпритировать порт. 
С помощью tsql -LH (server_name or ip addr) посмотрел все intance, там же показан номер порта, по которому удалось подключиться в классическом варианте.